# How to use JavaScript map to return object?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am using map JavaScript function to return an object. `row.id` throws error . I want to create id as key for every iteration in array.

```
<input value="3" id="first" class="pdate">
<input value="5" id="second" class="pdate">
<input value="2" id="third" class="pdate">
```

```
    if(document.querySelectorAll('.pdate')){
        let update = [...document.querySelectorAll('.pdate')].map(row => {
            return {
                row.id : row.value
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: If you want an object, map is the the answer....

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I tried but in js it showing error for ```row.id``` . i want expected output  as ```{
  "first": "3",
  "second": "5",
  "third": "2"
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to generate an object from the list of rows, use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const update = [...document.querySelectorAll('.pdate')].reduce((acc,row) => {
  acc[row.id] = row.value;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(update);
```

```html
<input value="3" id="first" class="pdate">
<input value="5" id="second" class="pdate">
<input value="2" id="third" class="pdate">
```

Comment: I just want single object that should hold all three property , not array list of objects

Comment: @Akhi21 if you want a map of id-value, you can use ``.reduce`` as above

Comment: what cant i use map? as i am asking generally?

Comment: In this case, ``.map`` is used to iterate an array. Since the end result should be an object, ``.reduce`` is the way to go

Comment: @Akhi21 that's ok, the important thing is that the problem was solved.

Comment: I was trying to add one more field before return statement using this is it right approach ```acc[section] = acc[row.id] ? document.getElementById("exid").value : null```

Comment: @Akhi21 please elaborate more, what are ``section`` and ``exid``? Can you add the expected output

Comment: actually i was thinking if i have to add one more property so key name is ```section```

Comment: @Akhi21 please update the question with the new requirements

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` to convert an array of key-value pairs to an object.

```js
let update = Object.fromEntries([...document.querySelectorAll('.pdate')]
   .map(row => [row.id, row.value]));
console.log(update);
```

```html
<input value="3" id="first" class="pdate">
<input value="5" id="second" class="pdate">
<input value="2" id="third" class="pdate">
```